# Dynamically change color on Android using openGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es, colors

How gradually change the color of the some shape with the time on Android using openGl?
For example, I want dynamically change the color of the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you mean something like this:

Measure time and get only remainder of the division on concrete module,
in my example, I use module = 10000 = 10 seconds, so each 10 seconds the set of colors will be repeated

```
int module = 10000;
long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % module;
```

And, then you can use this value, as you want - I create the next scenario, but you can modify it for obtaining the best result:

```
int shift = module/5;
Color c = new Color();
int red = (int)((float)time/module)*256, 
    green =(int)(((float)time+shift)/module)*256, 
    blue = (int)(((float)time+2*shift)/module)*256; 
c.rgb(red, green, blue);
```

if you would find better way, please inform me!